# QTKit Capture API: How to implement video screen recording (as in Quicktime X Player)?

Tags: cocoa, macos, quicktime, screen-capture

Does the QTKit Capture API support screen recording- i.e., can I specify the current screen output as the input source to record? If so, how?

Quicktime Player X supports screen recording, yet the [QTKit Capture API Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/QTKitApplicationProgrammingGuide/UsingQTKit/UsingQTKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008156-CH108-SW9) only mentions capturing from external cameras.

Answer (score 4):

Starting from Lion, you can use AVFoundation framework.
A quick tutorial can be found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1740/_index.html).

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be to capture static screenshots with the CGWindow API (search: Son of Grab), and append them to a [QTMovie](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/QuickTime/Reference/QTKitFramework/Classes/QTMovie_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/QTMovie/addImage:forDuration:withAttributes:) object using addImage:forDuration:withAttributes:

Related Apple Code example: StillMotion (developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/StillMotion/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: A different approach is to sidestep QTKit altogether and use OpenGL. 

Apple has sample code here: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/OpenGLScreenCapture/Introduction/Intro.html